# Jmeter Distributed Testing Not working with two way SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, jmeter, distributed-testing

I have tried to do distributed testing with two servers for a request which requires two way SSL handshaking. This is working fine when we are not using remote hosts for testing

```
sh jmeter.sh -n -t sample_Load_Test/sample_test.jmx -l sample_report/Log/results.jtl -e -o sample_report/Dashboard/
```

Jmeter Success:
[image: Jmeter Success]

But on trying to use the remote hosts for the same jmx file, the SSL handshake is failing. I have put the same same jmeter.p12 and truststore.jks in all the servers which are used for distribute testing.
Command used:

```
 sh jmeter.sh -n -t sample_test/sample_load_test.jmx -l sample_report/Log/results.jtl -e -o sample_report/Dashboard/ -r -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

Please see the error that I am getting

Jmeter Failure:
[image: Jmeter Failure]

> <httpSample t="20" it="0" lt="0" ct="20" ts="1545068074631" s="false"
>   lb="HTTP Request" rc="Non HTTP response code:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException" rm="Non HTTP response message:
>   Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible causes:

1. You use different [JRE versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) on master and slaves and they have different [SSL configuration in terms of storing certificates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2379/swmgrpkgscli-3/index.html). Make sure you use exactly the same Java runtime everywhere and configuration is the same.
2. Your test relies on [client certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) and on one of the slaves you don't have them defined in [*system.properties* file or in SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) make sure to use the same JMeter version and the same set of config files and external data files on each slave.

Get used to look into *jmeter.log* and/or *jmeter-server.log* files - in the majority of cases you should get the reason of the failure or unexpected behavior from the log.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for the support. I dont know what went wrong yesterday with the test setup. But today I have make sure everything is common between slaves(jmeter version, java version, SSL trust store and keystore in both slaves, running the test using only one slave at  a time and then do the combination). It is working perfectly as expected